# int variable increment from function

Tags: function, python-3.x

I am trying to get the input from my user to assign a 'faction' and based on following inputs modify the values for curAdvRep\curCrmRep.

The input shows that indise the funtion i get the desired result, but I need to be able to permanently modify the rep for the faction.

From file 2 called in file 1:

```
curAdvRep = 0
curCrmRep = 0
Crimson = "Crimson Brootherhood reputation: {0}".format(curCrmRep)
Advent = "Advent of Chaos reputation: {0}".format(curAdvRep)
PathSelDict = {'Advent' : Advent, 'Crimson' : Crimson, 'n' : n, 'c' : cont, 'd' : d, 'p' : p, 'l' : l}

def Faction (rep):
    global curAdvRep
    global curCrmRep
    global Advent
    global Crimson

    if rep in PathSelDict:
        if rep == 'Advent':
            curAdvRep += 50
            curCrmRep -= 5
            Advent = "Advent of Chaos reputation: {0}".format(curAdvRep)
            print(Advent)
            #print(Factions[JoinWorld])
        elif rep == 'Crimson':
            curAdvRep -= 5
            curCrmRep += 50
            print(PathSelDict[JoinWorld])
    else:
        print(Dismiss)
        sys.exit(0)
```

From file 1:

```
rep = input("Which side are you on? Advent or Crimson? ").title()
questfunc.Faction(rep)
print(Advent)
print(curAdvRep)
print(curCrmRep)
```

Output:

```
 Pick up the box or leave it alone? (p or l): p
Pick up the box
Reputation Gain
Advent of Chaos reputation: 5
Which side are you on? Advent or Crimson? advent
Advent of Chaos reputation: 55
Advent of Chaos reputation: 0
0
0
```

I am sorry if either my question or my code is offensive. I have researched an answer for my question, but due to either not finding a matching answer or my inability to translate an indirect answer to my specific question, I haven't found the solution.

Comment: Instead of simply down rating please tell me what im doing wrong...

I am trying to have my main program separate from my functions. Main=File 1, Functions=File2 . Main will gather and store input from the user and call the functions to pass the variables into. 

Based on the user input I need to modify the variable coming out of the function and have it persist to be used in later calls of that variable in both File 1 and file2.
Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a work around. For those that have also asked this question and had no helpful response, please take a look.

```
Choice1 = input(" Pick up the box or leave it alone? (p or l): ").lower()
RepGain(Choice1)
print(Advent, curAdvRep)


# Function for gain 
def RepGain (Choice):
    global curAdvRep
    global curCrmRep
    global Advent
    global Crimson

    if Choice in PathSelDict:
        if Choice == 'p':
            print('Reputation Gain\nAdvent + 100')
            curAdvRep += 100
            return curAdvRep
        elif Choice == 'l':
            print('Crimson + 100')
            curCrmRep += 100
            return curCrmRep 
        else:
            print(Dismiss)
            sys.exit(0)

Output:
Reputation Gain
Advent + 100
Advent of Chaos reputation: 100
```